# How to maintain state of object throughout the app and change the UI at the same time

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I'm developing an app having HomeFragment which displays posts of the user you are following. Now each post is having Like and Comment option and when you click on user profile pic or name, it will redirect you to his/her profile which again displays all his/her posts. Now again if you click on one of the post it will redirect you to post detail screen which implements ViewPager where you can change the post by swapping left or right.

My question is every post has Like and Comment option with Like and Comment count, if you like any one post then it should reflect at all the activities(Home, User profile and post detail).

Currently I'm handling all these using startActivityForResult and onActivityResult (eg: if you like post at position 2 and when you click back button then I'm sending that position with new count and notifying that particular position with new like count at HomeFragment) which is very confusing and I think is not the proper solution.

Is there any Design Pattern or any other mechanism to handle this?

If you didn't get my question then let me know, I'll elaborate it more.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have any servers?? Is everything client based?

Comment: use database to save your data.

Comment: Yes... I do have server.

Answer (score 1):

My approach in my apps:

In activity onCreate I start Intent service to load data from server. In Intent service data are loaded from server, then parsed and pushed to local database (I use super fast [Realm database](https://realm.io/products/realm-database/)). When intent service finished, UI is notified to refresh it's content. When you return to previous activity onResume is called where I reload data from database and refresh UI.

To sum it up, UI works only with local database where all data are stored. When new data are loaded on background thread, this data are also pushed to local database. So no need to send loaded data (only needed object ID's) between activities because database contains always up to date data.

Comment: The issue is, in HomePage server is returning post of all the users you are following. And when you click on particular user, server will return all posts of that selected user. Now you Liked some posts of that user and come back to HomePage I want that user's posts to be changed.

Comment: In your local database you store all the data. So when you want all posts for particular user in user detail, you make query in local database where post.user_id = ?. When you like his post, this change(like) is also stored in local database so when you go back to home page and refresh data everything is up to date :) Sorry, I dont see the issue.

Comment: I'm not using local database because it is not in the project scope that I'm working on and Home page gets only 10 posts at a time because of pagination and it doesn't contain all the post of a particular user. so if i click on particular user then in that user's profile activity I have another API to get all the posts of that user which again implements pagination.

Comment: Anyway I'm using Observer Design Pattern(I knew this Design pattern and was the last option to use but wanted to find better solution then this. I think this is also a great solution). I have observer which listens about the changes and when I like or comment particular post from user's activity, observer will be notified and changes would be made accordingly. I really appreciate your efforts and time and your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [singltone class](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) which will hold every posts likes and comments.
Every time you open activity/fragment you pull data from this class.
Every time user adds like or comment you push data to this class.

I also recomend you to take a look at [MVP pattern](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-mvp-for-beginners-25889c500443)